# How to move the cursor to a specific line in python

Tags: python, text-files, readline

I am reading data from a .txt file. I need to read lines, starting from a certain line, so I don't have to read the whole file (using .readlines()). Since I know which line i should start reading from, I came up with this(it does not work though):

```
def create_list(pos):
    list_created = []
    with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
        f.seek(pos)          #Here I want to put the cursor at the begining of the line that I need to read from
        line = f.readline()  #And here I read the first line
        while line != '<end>\n':       
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            list_created.append(line.split(' '))
            line = f.readline()
        f.close()
    return list_created

print(create_list(2))           #Here i need to create a list starting from the 3rd line of my file
```

And my text file looks something like this:

```
Something                               #line in pos= 0
<start>                                 #line in pos= 1
MY FIRST LINE                           #line in pos= 2
MY SECOND LINE                          #line in pos= 3
<end>
```

An the result should be somethign like:

```
[['MY', 'FIRST', 'LINE'], ['MY', 'SECOND', 'LINE']]
```

Basically, I need to start my readline() from a specific line.

Comment: If you are opening file with `with open` you don't need the `f.close()`

Comment: who told you `f.seek(pos)` skips `pos` lines?

Comment: Should I pass `pos` as a argument to the `readline()` method to start reading from the 3rd line?

Comment: if you haven't got to know the very basics yet. why do you care about performance so much? please make the application work(just readlines), then try to imporove performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? If you don't want to read the entire file with `.readlines()`, you can skip a single line by calling `.readline()`. This way you can call `readline()` as many times as you want to move your cursor down, then return the next line. Also, I don't recommend using `line != '<end>\n'` unless you're absolutely sure that there will be a newline after `<end>`. Instead, do something like `not '<end>' in line`:

```py
def create_list(pos):
    list_created = []
    with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
        for i in range(pos):
            f.readline()
        line = f.readline()  #And here I read the first line
        while not '<end>' in line:       
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            list_created.append(line.split(' '))
            line = f.readline()
        f.close()
    return list_created

print(create_list(2))           #Here i need to create a list starting from the 3rd line of my file
```

text_file.txt:

```
Something
<start>
MY FIRST LINE
MY SECOND LINE
<end>
```

Output:

```
[['MY', 'FIRST', 'LINE'], ['MY', 'SECOND', 'LINE']]
```